# How do I remove a car from my hangar? (Offline)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Playing as Trevor. For some reason I have a Crusader in my Hangar. Of course, I don't WANT a vehicle that can't fly in my Hangar. I took the Crusader outside, blew it up, but it respawns when I switch to it again.

I want a Luxor and my Hangar is full with that single Crusader and I can't get rid of the Crusader to replace it with the Luxor... without actually having the Luxor to replace it with.

Is there some way that I can disown or otherwise give up possession of a vehicle that's in my hangar?

Answer (score 0):

That part of the game is very glitchy. I recommend taking it out, blowing it up (or just ditching it) and getting another vehicle (the one you want) and park it in there. I am pretty sure the new vehicle you save in there will overwrite the one you are trying to get rid of.

As a side bit of advice, be careful what vehicles you mod..except the main default vehicles. If you default a main vehicle then the chances of it staying modded throughout the game are very high. I modded Trevor's truck and Franklin's car and I use them to mod as I get throughout the game, and so far they have not gotten reset at all. I have heard stuff online about them resetting occasionally, but I haven't had this issue and it shouldn't happen very often.

Answer (score -2):

If it's in the private hanger then it will work, but not the one that has the plane/car symbol (Trevor's weapon delivery site) as this has only one plane for his jobs.